# MySql Left Join update Where column Like

Tags: mysql, database

Can someone look at this and tell me what syntax issues I am getting?

```
UPDATE `oc_product` p LEFT JOIN 'oc_product_description' d on p.product_id = d.product_id SET p.image = "/catalog/tonerthumb.gif" WHERE d.description like '%toner%'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it not tell you when you attempt to execute the command? For one though, it looks like you are using the wrong quote types  for your join table. Also, I am more familiar with Oracle, but you are using double quotes, instead of single, when doing a, im guessing, string compare for the value of `p.image`.

Comment: You're using single quotes for the 2nd table name, making it a string.

Comment: Ah That was it! Sneaky quotes. Thank you good sir.

Comment: @MikołajDziwulski - I have added an expanded version of my comment as an answer. Could you accept it as such if it fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework question, but since I already mostly answered it in my comment, I'll just go ahead and move it down here to an actual answer and add some explanation.

Your query:

```
UPDATE `oc_product` p 
LEFT JOIN 'oc_product_description' d 
ON p.product_id = d.product_id 
SET p.image = "/catalog/tonerthumb.gif" 
WHERE d.description like '%toner%'
```

The primary problem you have is that you are using single quotes in an attempt to delimit an object. Back-ticks are used for that. Single quotes are using as a string delimiter. In my comment above, I mentioned that double-quotes may not be correct for a string delimiter, but after looking it up, you can actually use single or double quotes interchangeably in mysql, so you can ignore that bit. The only real problem you have is the single-quote vs back-tick.

In order for your query to be correctly formed, you just need to replace the single-quotes with back-ticks on the join clause of your query:

```
UPDATE `oc_product` p 
LEFT JOIN `oc_product_description` d 
ON p.product_id = d.product_id 
SET p.image = "/catalog/tonerthumb.gif" 
WHERE d.description like '%toner%'
```

Although the double quotes are fine to sue for string delimiters, as I mentioned, it is better to be consistent when writing queries, so I would go ahead and change the query just to bring some consistency:

```
UPDATE `oc_product` p 
LEFT JOIN `oc_product_description` d 
ON p.product_id = d.product_id 
SET p.image = '/catalog/tonerthumb.gif' 
WHERE d.description like '%toner%';
```

I would also get into the habit of ending all of your queries explicitly with a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax in MySQL is as below:

```
UPDATE `oc_product` p 
LEFT JOIN `oc_product_description` d 
ON p.product_id = d.product_id 
SET p.image = '/catalog/tonerthumb.gif' 
WHERE d.description like '%toner%';
```